# How do I add categories, shutdown and reboot icons to GNOME shell overview on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

How can I add the above options to GNOME shell overview on Ubuntu 18.04.

Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME shell mock-up:
[image: Ubuntu 18.04 gnome shell mock-up]

Answer (score 0):

**Application categories**

You can't without editing the source code. Early incarnations of Gnome Shell had such categories, but the feature was dropped.

You may functionally get close to this functionality by organizing your applications in application folders. The "official" way to do this is pretty hidden, and involves the use of "Software".

- Go to the "Installed" tab.
- Click the checkmark sign in the top bar, left of the "hamburger" menu.
- Select the applications you want to move in a Category.
- When done, click "Add to folder".
- An "Application folder" dialog appears. You can either add to an existing folder, or create a new one.

An "unofficial" but likely more powerful way to work with application folders can be achieved installing the Gnome Shell extension [Appfolders Management extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/).

**Power management buttons (Shut down, Log off...)**

Icons are by default present in more recent Ubuntu versions. If they are not yet present in Ubuntu 18.04, then you can create your own by creating corresponding .desktop files in the folder ~/.local/share/applications. Copying and pasting following code in a terminal will do that automatically for you:

```
/bin/cat <<EOM >~/.local/share/applications/shutdown.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown
Comment=Shutdown system
Exec=gnome-session-quit --power-off
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=system-shutdown
Categories=GTK;Utility;
Keywords=Shut Down;Power Off;
StartupNotify=true
EOM

/bin/cat <<EOM > ~/.local/share/applications/reboot.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Reboot
Comment=Reboot system
Exec=gnome-session-quit --reboot
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=system-reboot
Categories=GTK;Utility;
Keywords=Start again;Restart;
StartupNotify=true
EOM

/bin/cat <<EOM >~/.local/share/applications/logout.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Logout
Comment=Log out of system
Exec=gnome-session-quit --logout
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=system-logout
Categories=GTK;Utility;
Keywords=Log out;Sign off;
StartupNotify=true
EOM

/bin/cat <<EOM >~/.local/share/applications/suspend.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Suspend
Comment=Suspend system
Exec=systemctl suspend -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=system-suspend
Categories=GTK;Utility;
Keywords=Sleep;
StartupNotify=true
EOM
```

Comment: none of the above worked for me. I want it to look just like the mock-up so I won't have to type 'shutdown' or 'logout' to perform these operations

Comment: 1) You can add the log-out/shut down to the main screen 2) With the same two clicks, you can shutdown from the user menu 3) I said you can't achieve what you want (without programming, this is open source after all). That effectively answers the question. As an extra, I provide a possible option to make it more like you want. If none of these work, then you should  explore a different desktop environment.